# entry into Germany

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, us-citizens, trusted-traveler

I believe I read that there is a Global Entry type card US Citizens can get at Airports in Germany that is like a quick pass thru customs. Does anyone know the story on that?

Comment: what do you want to know about it in particular> Who is eligible? How to apply?

Comment: I guess that you mean "pass though immigration" - Customs is super-fast in Germany - you go through a gate and you're done (unless you have anything to declare *or* are picked for a random check).

Comment: I was in Europe last week travelling on my US passport (since I forgot to bring my EU passport that I typically bring as well). Smooth sailing on all fronts, everything was quick and easy. While Global Entry is incredibly valuable in entering the US, it won't make much of a difference in Germany

Answer (score 5):

There is. It's [the EasyPASS system](https://www.easypass.de/EasyPass/EN/EasyPASS-RTP/rtp_node.html), which allows you to use eGates at immigration at German airports. It's available through a special bilateral agreement between the US and Germany. These are the gates normally for EU/EEA/CH citizens, but there's an extra step for EasyPASS travelers to see an officer and get a passport stamp

All the details are on the linked page and their [FAQ](https://www.easypass.de/EasyPass/EN/Service/FAQ/faq_node.html). The service is free, but you have to complete an application form and visit [an enrollment center](https://www.easypass.de/EasyPass/EN/Where_do_I_find_EasyPASS/where_do_i_find_easypass_node.html;jsessionid=3209C438ABFD5AE28696EAFA7DCAA60D.2_cid334) run by the German Federal Police (outside the secure area of the airport, which I've never managed to find the time to do). It only works in Germany, so it's only useful if your first point of entry to the Schengen area is Germany, not if you're going through immigration in another country and transiting to Germany.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much